How to turn 2 images, last frame and overlay, into a 5 second end-roll using FFmpeg?
I would like to turn 2 images, last frame and overlay, into a 5 second end-roll using ffmpeg

The last frame would be in color.
From 0 to 5 seconds, the last frame will fade to gray + increased blur with each second passed.
From 0 to 5 seconds, fade in the overlay on top of the last frame, it should retain its color.

ffmpeg -f lavfi ^
-i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 ^
-loop 1 -i "frame.png" ^
-pix_fmt yuv420p -t 5 ^
-vf scale=1280:720 ^
end-roll.mp4

I was not able to get beyond the above.
Also saw this Medium post, but was not sure how to process from an image instead.

ffmpeg \
    -loop 1 -i frame.png \
    -loop 1 -i credits.png \
    -filter_complex "
        [0:v]split=2[base][blurred];
        [1:v]fade=type=in:start_time=1:duration=1:alpha=1[credits];
        [blurred]boxblur=luma_radius=50:chroma_radius=25:luma_power=1[blurred];
        [blurred]monochrome[blurredgray];
        [blurredgray]fade=type=in:start_time=0:duration=3:alpha=1[blurred-with-fadein];
        [base][blurred-with-fadein]overlay[blurout];
        [blurout][credits]overlay[output]
    " \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -t 5 \
    -map "[output]" \
    -y blurout.mp4

After some tinkering, the above kind of works:

It crossfades between the original and blurred version
That can pass off as gradual blurring to the untrained eye
But if you have fonts/text involved, you will see the text fade out rather than blur out

And now, to extract the last frame of my video.
